# Using parse database for both Android and Web

Tags: android, database, web, parse-server

Hey guys I am new to android development I just created an app for android using back4app parse database where data stored in classes hope you are familiar with that and now I want to use the same data for my website using the same parse database please help me and suggest me something good to do this

Comment: Use sqlite for the database it will be more useful than that database that your using(on android).Use mysql on the web....Create some JSON on the web over php(for example),send it to your app(use volley to receive it on the app).And you can use the same JSON on your web by using Angular(react,polymer.....)

Comment: No I have all done with app and now want to use that parse data with website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse-server store your data in a MongoDB database means that after the data is being stored you can access it from any device at any location. In your case you can start with a Web app, read, create, update and delete data and then you can just create an android app and use the same API's there and you will see exactly the same data that you see in your web app (if the logic is the same of course).

The best way to get started is with [parse Javascript SDK](http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/) for your web app and [parse android SDK](http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/) for your android app.

Later, you can create it for iOS or any other platform that you like. If for some reason you don't have the relevant SDK for your technology you can always use parse-server REST api's

If you need more info or have specific issue please let me know.

Comment: Hey Ran Hassid Thanks for your suggestion as I told that I have done all my work related android app and now I want to use that database for my website and you suggest me parse JavaScript SDK but I don't know how to set it up and the above link about that is so messy so if there is any tutorial regarding it or if u know how to do it please let me know

Comment: When you create your website you can use the parse javascript SDK: http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/ there you can see examples on how to create/read/update and delete objects from your parse server instance. This SDK can integrated to any web technology that you are using easily (either via requireJS or by adding the script into as javascript tag in your html page)

Comment: sure. Glad to help .